# Multi-level defaultdict with variable depth and with list and int type

Tags: python, dictionary, defaultdict

I am trying to create a multi-level dict with variable depth and with list and int type.

Data structure is like below

```
A
--B1
-----C1=1
-----C2=[1]
--B2=[3]
D
--E
----F
------G=4
```

In the case of above data structure, the last value can be an `int` or `list`.

If the above data structure has the **only int** then I can be easily achieved by using the below code:

```
from collections import defaultdict
f = lambda: defaultdict(f)
d = f()
d['A']['B1']['C1'] = 1
```

But as the last value has **both** **list** and **int**, it becomes a bit problematic for me.

Now we can insert data in a list using two ways.

```
d['A']['B1']['C2']= [1]
d['A']['B1']['C2'].append([2])
```

But when I am using only the append method it is causing the error.

Error is:

```
AttributeError: 'collections.defaultdict' object has no attribute 'append'
```

so Is there any way to use only the **append** method for a **list**?

Comment: How is the type decided?

Comment: What's the issue with doing `d['A']['B1']['C2'] = [1]`?

Comment: In a list, we normally use **append function** to insert any data in a list . when I am using `d['A']['B1']['C2'].append([1])` , it causing error.

Comment: That's right, because you defined the default value to be a `defaultdict` which has no `append` method. `d['A']['B1']['C2'] = [1]` is what you should do before appending. just like you do `d['A']['B1']['C1'] = 1`.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary - Thanks for your reply. I have edited my question to raise my problem properly.

Comment: With `d['A']['B1']['C2'] = [1]`, `d['A']['B1']['C2'].append([2])` should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way you can use your current `defaultdict`-based structure to make `d['A']['B1']['C2'].append(1)` work properly if the `'C2'` key doesn't already exist, since the data structure can't tell that the unknown key should correspond to a list rather than another layer of dictionary. It doesn't know what method you're going to call on the value it returns, so it can't know it shouldn't return a dictionary (like it did when it first looked up `'A'` and `'B'`).

This isn't an issue for bare integers, since for those you're as assigning directly to a new key (and all the earlier levels are dictionaries). When you're assigning, the data structure isn't creating the value, you are, so you can use any type you want.

Now, if your keys are distinctive in some way, so that given a key like `'C2'` you can know for sure that it should correspond to a list, you may have a chance. You can write your own `dict` subclass, defining a `__missing__` method to handle lookups of keys that don't exist yet in your own special way:

```
def Tree(dict):
    def __missing__(self, key):
        if key_corresponds_to_list(key): # magic from somewhere
            result = self[key] = []
        else:
            result = self[key] = Tree()
        return result

    # you might also want a custom __repr__
```

Here's an example run with a magic key function that makes any even-length key default to a list, while an odd-length key defaults to a dict:

```
> def key_corresponds_to_list(key):
    return len(key) % 2 == 0

> t = Tree()

> t["A"]["B"]["C2"].append(1) # the default value for C2 is a list because it's even length

> t
{'A': {'B': {'C2': [1]}}}

> t["A"]["B"]["C10"]["D"] = 2 # C10's another layer of dict, since it's length is odd

> t
{'A': {'B': {'C10': {'D': 2}, 'C2': [1]}}} # it didn't matter what length D was though
```

You probably won't actually want to use a global function to control the class like this, I just did that as an example. If you go with this approach, I'd suggest putting the logic directly into the `__missing__` method (or maybe passing a function as a parameter, like `defaultdict` does with its factory function).